# Insert new dataframe to existing dataframe into specific row position in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df1` and `df2` as follows:

**df1:**

```
   a   b   c
0  1   2   4
1  6  12  24
2  7  14  28
3  4   8  16
4  3   6  12
```

**df2:**

```
    a   b   c
0   7   8   9
1  10  11  12
```

How can I insert `df2` to `df1` but after the second row? My desired output will like this.

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   4
1   6  12  24
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
4   7  14  28
5   4   8  16
6   3   6  12
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with splitted first `DataFrame` by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1.iloc[:2], df2, df1.iloc[2:]], ignore_index=False)
print (df)
    a   b   c
0   1   2   4
1   6  12  24
0   7   8   9
1  10  11  12
2   7  14  28
3   4   8  16
4   3   6  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
df2.index=range(len(df1),len(df1)+len(df2)) #change index where df1 ends
final=pd.concat((df1,df2)) #concat
final.iloc[np.r_[0,1,df2.index,2:len(df1)]] #select ordering with iloc
#final.iloc[np.r_[0:2,df2.index,2:len(df1)]]
```

---

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   4
1   6  12  24
5   7   8   9
6  10  11  12
2   7  14  28
3   4   8  16
4   3   6  12
```